# Why does the likelihood of a random sample drawn from a Gaussian process change with the number of indices in this fashion?

Tags: likelihood, gaussian-process

I made some experiments to better understand how the likelihood of samples drawn from a Gaussian process change depending on the number of indices. For that purpose, I drew for different number of indices some samples, calculated their likelihood, and then took the mean of all samples (see python code at end of post). This resulted in following plot (careful: y-axis logarithmic):

[image: see code for origin]

My assumption was that since the sample space increases with the number of indexes, the likelihood would get lower with increased number of indexes. Instead the we have a curve with a local minima at 3 (which is suspiciously close to $e$, but that might be pure coincidence) and then increases exponentially.

Why does this curve have the shape it has? Is there also a way to calculate this algebraic?

Python code that created the plot (simplified pseudo code below):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tfd = tfp.distributions
psd_kernels = tfp.math.psd_kernels

# The different number of indices we are going to evaluate
n_indices = range(1, 10)
# number of samples we are going to draw, higher == more stable
nsamples = 1000
# define some kernel, default values: amplitude=1., length_scale=1.
kernel = psd_kernels.ExponentiatedQuadratic() 
# initialize empty list for storing results
prob_mean_list = []
# run for each n_index
for n_index in n_indices:
    # create x-axis indices
    index_points = np.expand_dims(np.linspace(-1., 1., n_index), -1)
    # initialize GP
    gp = tfd.GaussianProcess(
        kernel=kernel,
        index_points=index_points)
    # draw nsamples samples from the GP
    samples = gp.sample(nsamples)
    # calc the likelihood for each sample
    prob = gp.prob(samples)
    # take the mean of all likelihoods and store it for plotting
    prob_mean = np.mean(prob.numpy())
    prob_mean_list.append(prob_mean)

plt.scatter(n_indices, prob_mean_list)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel("Number of indices")
plt.ylabel("likelihood")
plt.title("average likelihood of sampled timeseries\n depending on the number of indices")
plt.show()
```

Pseudo code of the python code:

```
for each number of indices n (1 to 9):
    draw 1000 samples from a gaussian process with n indexes (each sample is a vector of lenght n). It uses an exponentiated quadratic kernel with amplitude = 1 and length scale = 1.
    calculate the likelihood of obtaining each sample
    take the mean of all likelyhoods
    plot this mean value
```

Comment: Do you evalutate the likelihood at the true parameter values?  Or do you take the mean of the maximum likelihood?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question correctly. But as an example, the simplest case is the first iteration of the loop, where the number of indexes is one; as such we just have a univariate normal distribution with a mean of 0. Then I draw 1000 samples from that and calculate the likelyhood of obtaining each of those values (which would be high near 0, and low if far away from zero). Then i take the mean of all these likelyhoods.

Comment: The kernel parameters are always the same, and the mean is always zero, therefore a vector of zeros would always be the most likely sample, no matter the number of indexes

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know Python, it's hard to tell exactly what you do in your simulations.  But assuming that you're evaluating the Gaussian likelihood
$$
L(\mathbf{x}) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}(\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma))^{-1/2}\exp\{-\frac12(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)^T\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)\}
$$
at the true parameter values, then the expected value, since the quadratic form in the last term is chi-square with $n$ degrees of freedom, is
\begin{align}
E(L(\mathbf{x})) 
  &= (2\pi)^{-n/2}(\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma))^{-1/2}M_{\chi_n^2}(-1/2)
\\&= (2\pi)^{-n/2}(\det(\boldsymbol\Sigma))^{-1/2}2^{-n/2}.
\end{align}
where $M_{\chi_n^2}$ is the mgf of the chi-square distribution.
The log of this is
$$
\ln E(L(\mathbf{x})) =-\frac n2\ln 2\pi -\ln\det\boldsymbol(\Sigma)-\frac n2\ln 2.
$$
For the [quadratic exponential autocovariance function](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/psd_kernels/ExponentiatedQuadratic) you're using, the log of the determinant of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is not linear in $n$ as opposed to the case of iid observations so that may explain the curvature you see in your plot.

Comment: I am currently studying your answer - sorry for being slow with accepting/commenting, but i first need some time to fully understand it